# Значение производной в точке по схеме Горнера

Tags: c, численные-методы

Дана задача, найти значение полинома и производной полинома в точке по схеме Горнера.
Ввод осуществляется в стандартный поток и имеет вид х, a_n, a_n-1, a_n-2,...,a_0, то есть количество коэффициентов a_i определяет степень полинома. Метод Горнера для нахождения производной легко доступен в сети, удалось его реализовать в коде. А вот способ найти производную методом Горнера не получается найти. Подскажите, пожалуйста, реализацию:

Сейчас код с обычным разностным методом выглядит так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float eps = 0.0001;

int main(void){
    int c;
    float x, a_i, result_x0=0, result_x1=0;
    scanf("%f", &x);
    
    while (1) {
        c = scanf("%f", &a_i);
        if ( c == EOF ) break ;
        result_x0 = a_i + result_x0*x;
        result_x1 = a_i + result_x1*(x+eps);
    } 
    printf("\nResult: %g\n",result_x0);
    printf("1st Derivative: %g\n", (result_x1-result_x0)/(eps));
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть такая возможность у схемы Горнера.
Код для массива, но у вас коэффициенты вводятся как раз в нужном порядке, так что модифицировать нетрудно. p - значение полинома, dp - производная.

Источник: Numerical Recipes in C, с.5.3 или 5.1 в зависимости от издания

```
p=c[n-1];
dp=0.;
for(j=n-2;j>=0;j--) {
   dp=dp*x+p; 
   p=p*x+c[j];
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Это та самая "двухшаговая" схема Горнера, которую я искал!

Comment: Век живи — век учись... :) Красивая схема!

Answer (score 2):

А не проще запомнить все коэффициенты (жаль, что `n` не известно заранее...) и вычислять производную как полином?

```
int main()
{
    double x, a[100], f = 0, d = 0;
    int n = 0;

    scanf("%lf", &x);
    for(;scanf("%lf", &a[n]) == 1; ++n) f = f*x + a[n];
    for(int N = --n, i = 0; i < N; ++i) d = d * x + n--*a[i];
    printf("\nn = %d\n",n);
    printf("\nResult: %lf\n",f);
    printf("1st Derivative: %lf\n", d);
}
```

Здесь один минус — массив `a` или надо брать заранее достаточного размера, или выделять через `malloc` и возиться с его динамическим расширением при необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо за решение! А как выглядел бы вариант с расширением памяти?

Comment: Отслеживание, сколько элементов из выделенных заняты. Когда заполнено все, и нужно еще — выделение новой памяти (например, в два раза большей) через `realloc`. Словом, реализация вектора из С++...